# Templates and constant strings

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a function I'm wanting to template, at the moment I have two different versions for `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

The function (stripped down) is like this

```
template <class T, class _Tc>
std::vector<T> TokenizeArgs(const T& in) {
const T tofind = T("\"' ");
.. do stuff ..
}
```

`T` is either `std::string` or `std::wstring` and `_Tc` is either `char` or `wchar_t`. I'm having an issue getting the constant strings I define to work in the template version. The above code works for `std::string` but not for `std::wstring` because there is no constructor for `std::wstring` which takes a `char*` array. Normally to fix this I'd declare the constant string as `const T tofind = L"\"' "`, but then it wouldn't work with `std::string`.

I don't have much experience with templates and so I don't really know how to fix this issue.

Comment: @BЈовић Well I would've thought so because the functions are otherwise identical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the const creation into its own factory function and specialize the function for `string` and `wstring` seperately.

```
const T tofind = CreateConst<T>();


template <class T>
const T CreateConst();

template <>
const std::string CreateConst<std::string>()
{
     return std::string("\"' ");
}

template <>
const std::wstring CreateConst<std::wstring>()
{
     return std::wstring(L"\"' ");
}
```